# Casting from ArrayList<Object> to my own class

Tags: java, arraylist

I have two ArrayLists, teamList1 and teamList2, which each contain five Team objects. I'm comparing those contents to each other in one of my methods. I **must** pass in these two ArrayLists as a single 2-element simple array argument, Objects[], into the method. I'm getting a compiler error because I'm struggling with casting from type Objects into type Team. In other words, changing from a Collection to a simple array back to a Collection is giving me an error. Anyone have a tip on my casting error?

**CommonElements.java**

```
package test;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.*;

public class CommonElements {

    List<Comparable> teamList1 = new ArrayList<Comparable>();
    List<Comparable> teamList2 = new ArrayList<Comparable>();  
    List<Comparable> commonList = new ArrayList<Comparable>();

    Object[] listCollection = new Object[2];   
    int comparisonCount;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new CommonElements();       
    }

    public CommonElements() {

        comparisonCount = 0;

        Team a = new Team("Boston");
        Team b = new Team("Seattle");
        Team c = new Team("Newark");
        Team d = new Team("Houston");
        Team e = new Team("Salt Lske City");

        teamList1.add(a);
        teamList1.add(b);
        teamList1.add(c);
        teamList1.add(d);
        teamList1.add(e);

        Team f = new Team("Seattle");
        Team g = new Team("Nashville");
        Team h = new Team("St. Louis");
        Team i = new Team("New York");
        Team j = new Team("Boston");

        teamList2.add(f);
        teamList2.add(g);
        teamList2.add(h);
        teamList2.add(i);
        teamList2.add(j);    


        listCollection[0] = teamList1;
        listCollection[1] = teamList2;

        findCommonElements(listCollection);
        System.out.println(comparisonCount);          
    }

    public Comparable[] findCommonElements(Object[] collections)
    {        
        ArrayList<Object> objectTeam1 = new ArrayList<Object>(Arrays.asList(collections[0]));
        ArrayList<Object> objectTeam2 = new ArrayList<Object>(Arrays.asList(collections[1]));

        ArrayList<Team> team1 = (ArrayList)objectTeam1;
        ArrayList<Team> team2 = (ArrayList)objectTeam2;


        Team[] commonList = new Team[5];
        int  i = 0;
        for(Team x:team1)
        {
            for(Team y:team2)
            {       
                comparisonCount++;
                if(x.compareTo(y) == 0)
                { 
                    commonList[i] = x;                      
                    System.out.println(commonList[i].teamName); 
                    i++;
                    break; /*to ensure it looks for only one match per entry*/                    
                }
            } 
        }        
        return commonList;
    }

    public int getComparisons()
    {
        return comparisonCount;
    }
}
```

**Team.java**

```
package test;

public class Team implements Comparable<Team> {

    String teamName = new String();

    public void setName ( String n ) {
        teamName = n;
    } 

    public Team(String n) {
        setName(n);
    }


    public int compareTo(Team x)
    {
        if(this.teamName.equals(x.teamName))
        {
            return 0;
        }
        else
        {
            return -1;
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: welcome to stack overflow. can you post the error log ? @shampouya

Comment: You can't cast generics (I don't believe), e.g. `ArrayList<Object>` to `ArrayList<Team>`...and I don't understand why that's at all necessary here.  You have an array of `Comparable` objects, so why not have your `compareElements` method take an array of `Comparable` objects instead and not do any casting?

Answer (score 3):

That is a very unfortunate and odd way of passing the arguments, but anyway, to make it work, you can do:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
ArrayList<Team> team1 = (ArrayList<Team>)collections[0];
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
ArrayList<Team> team2 = (ArrayList<Team>)collections[1];
```

Your existing code was taking each ArrayList, putting it into a one element array, wrapping that array as a list, creating an ArrayList from it, and trying to view the `ArrayList<ArrayList<Team>>` as an `ArrayList<Team>`.

A few other things I see... you don't need to assign these to variables if you're only using them to add to the list:

```
Team a = new Team("Boston");
...
teamList1.add(a);
```

You can simply do:

```
teamList1.add(new Team("Boston"));
```

You don't need to create the `listCollection` array separately, because you can create it inline when passing the arguments:

```
findCommonElements(new Object[] { teamList1, teamList2 });
```

In your Team class, this:

```
String teamName = new String();
```

Should simply be:

```
String teamName;
```

In your compareTo method:

```
public int compareTo(Team x)
{
    if(this.teamName.equals(x.teamName))
    {
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        return -1;
    }
}
```

That should be:

```
public int compareTo(Team x)
{
    return teamName.compareTo(x.teamName);
}
```

which is shorter, and honors [the compareTo requirement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html#compareTo-T-) that `sgn(x.compareTo(y)) == -sgn(y.compareTo(x))` for all x and y.